# Can i add a .xap file into another project

Tags: silverlight, xap

Basically i want to utilize the [Silverlight Video player on Codeplex](http://sl2videoplayer.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=21749) in another Silverlight application. Is this possible. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a few assemblies of interest, such as those video player .dll files, then you could of course:

1. Rename the .xap to .zip
2. Extract the contents
3. Copy the .dll assemblies into your project
4. Reference the .dll's

Unfortunately, I'm guessing that you might be wanting to take advantage of the actual video player application - which includes custom handling for init parameters of the control, and just include that .Xap file into your solution. I don't know of an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

adding another xap file to your project, yes. you'll need to manually load the assemblies inside the xap package to utilize it.

Check the downloadable project solution here: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/06/21/dynamic-localization-in-silverlight.aspx

the solution basically has two silverlight projects, the ExternalResources project's generated xap gets created and it's assemblies are manually loaded when needed.